# JupyterHub: 404 error. Can't find call_back url

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyterhub

I'm trying to install jupyterhub using docker-compose. It fails with the following message:

```
  I 2020-01-31 16:30:48.424 JupyterHub oauth2:100] OAuth redirect: 'http://35.226.65.183:30100/hub/oauth_callback'
[I 2020-01-31 16:30:48.425 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/oauth_login?next= -> http://35.226.65.183:30080/auth/realms/ma
ster/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F35.226.65.183%3A30100%2Fhub%2Foauth_callbac
k&client_id=jupyterhub&state=[secret] (@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 1.69ms
[E 2020-01-31 16:31:27.259 JupyterHub web:1788] Uncaught exception GET /hub/oauth_callback?state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICJjZmZlM
jk3ZTVmN2M0NjhjODFjZjVhMGEzOTQ5MmVkYyIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6ICIifQ%3D%3D&session_state=b8884ec6-666c-4749-8762-34e837ca5f55&cod
e=671dd549-dca0-4921-90a7-4be854da548b.b8884ec6-666c-4749-8762-34e837ca5f55.946f3792-de4d-4a5e-9f7e-17d05cb87c81 (::ffff:1
92.0.161.155)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='35.226.65.183:30100', method='GET', uri='/hub/oauth_callback?state=eyJzdGF0ZV
9pZCI6ICJjZmZlMjk3ZTVmN2M0NjhjODFjZjVhMGEzOTQ5MmVkYyIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6ICIifQ%3D%3D&session_state=b8884ec6-666c-4749-8762-3
4e837ca5f55&code=671dd549-dca0-4921-90a7-4be854da548b.b8884ec6-666c-4749-8762-34e837ca5f55.946f3792-de4d-4a5e-9f7e-17d05cb
87c81', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::ffff:192.0.161.155')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 207, in get
        user = await self.login_user()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 699, in login_user
        authenticated = await self.authenticate(data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/auth.py", line 383, in get_authenticated_user
        authenticated = await maybe_future(self.authenticate(handler, data))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/oauthenticator/generic.py", line 138, in authenticate
        resp = await http_client.fetch(req)
    tornado.httpclient.HTTPClientError: HTTP 404: Not Found

[E 2020-01-31 16:31:27.261 JupyterHub log:166] {
      "X-Forwarded-Host": "35.226.65.183:30100",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "30100",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "::ffff:192.0.161.155",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "Cookie": "oauthenticator-state=[secret]",
      "Connection": "close",
      "Referer": "http://35.226.65.183:30080/auth/realms/master/login-actions/registration?client_id=jupyterhub&tab_id=LZ-
UwbTzssM",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0",
      "Host": "35.226.65.183:30100"
    }
[E 2020-01-31 16:31:27.261 JupyterHub log:174] 500 GET /hub/oauth_callback?state=[secret]&session_state=[secret]&code=[sec
ret] (@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 6.88ms
16:31:44.666 [ConfigProxy] info: 200 GET /api/routes 
[I 2020-01-31 16:31:44.666 JupyterHub proxy:320] Checking routes


Uncaught exception GET /hub/oauth_callback?state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICJhOGZkO
TcxNmM0MTg0NmI1ODAyMjYyZGM3OTdjYjEwMSIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6ICIifQ%3D%3D&session_state=b757af0b-2e63-42cd-8900-b08bf485b64b&cod
e=ebd0a4c6-76e1-459f-9e29-99c0a3b7eb6e.b757af0b-2e63-42cd-8900-b08bf485b64b.946f3792-de4d-4a5e-9f7e-17d05cb87c81 (::ffff:1
92.0.161.155)
```

When I directly hit the url on the browser `http://35.226.65.183:30100/hub/oauth_callback?state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICJhOGZkO
TcxNmM0MTg0NmI1ODAyMjYyZGM3OTdjYjEwMSIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6ICIifQ%3D%3D&session_state=b757af0b-2e63-42cd-8900-b08bf485b64b&cod
e=ebd0a4c6-76e1-459f-9e29-99c0a3b7eb6e.b757af0b-2e63-42cd-8900-b08bf485b64b.946f3792-de4d-4a5e-9f7e-17d05cb87c81`, it works in the way that it does not give me a 404 error but the page is found but it's some kind of invalid state error.
My docker-compose yaml file is:

```
version: "2"

services:
  hub:
    restart: always
    image: localhost:5000/fifteenrock/jhub_image:0.1
    container_name: jhub
    ports:
      - ${JHUB_PORT}:8000
    volumes:
      # Bind Docker socket on the host so we can connect to the daemon from
      # within the container
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw"
      # Bind Docker volume on host for JupyterHub database and cookie secrets
      - "data:${DATA_VOLUME_CONTAINER}"
    environment:
      CLIENT_ID: ${CLIENT_ID}
      # CLIENT_SECRET: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
      CLIENT_SECRET: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
      HOST_URL: ${HOST_URL}
      NOTEBOOK_URL: ${NOTEBOOK_URL}
      FR_IMAGE_TAG: ${FR_IMAGE_TAG}
      DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME: ${DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME}
      HUB_IP: should_be_ip_address_without_http
            # All containers will join this network
      DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME: ${DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME}
      # Noebook directory inside user image
      DOCKER_NOTEBOOK_DIR: ${DOCKER_NOTEBOOK_DIR}
      # Using this run command (optional)
      DOCKER_SPAWN_CMD: ${DOCKER_SPAWN_CMD}

volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: ${DATA_VOLUME_HOST}
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME}
```

My script which creates the containers is(I have elided variables which may not be relevant)

```
app_host=http://35.226.65.183
...
export JHUB_PORT=30100
export DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME=jhub
export HOST_URL=$app_host:30080
export NOTEBOOK_URL=$app_host:$JHUB_PORT
$BIN_DIR/docker-compose up -d
```